# Spring Framework 3.2 : How to add basic authentication for all Requests through RestTemplate

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, basic-authentication, resttemplate

I'm working on a Spring framework 3.2 version project. Requirement is to call an external Web-service which requires basic authentication.

Currently, I'm using HttpClient and adding basic authentication into header. but this is being done for each requests. I know in Spring Boot we can achieve that by using *RestTemplateBuilder*. IS there a way we can maintain a single authentication for all the requests by adding authentication only once?

TIA

Answer (score 0):

You can define a `RestTemplate` bean with authentication details like this:

```
@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    return builder.basicAuthorization("user", "secret").build();
}
```

**Updated**

An alternative way to do this is by implementing an interceptor. `RestTemplate` extends the `InterceptingHttpAccessor` interface which has a `setInterceptors()` method. You can use it to inject an interceptor to set request headers as needed.

```
public class MyInterceptor implements ClientHttpRequestInterceptor {
 
    @Override
    public ClientHttpResponse intercept(HttpRequest request, byte[] body, ClientHttpRequestExecution execution) throws IOException {
        // ... set headers on the request ...
        return execution.execute(request, body);
    }
}

@Bean
public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();
    restTemplate.setInterceptors(Collections.singletonList(new MyInterceptor()))
    return restTemplate
}
```

Note: untested code, but should work. You can check the docs for more details.

https://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.2.0.RELEASE/javadoc-api/index.html?org/springframework/web/client/RestTemplate.html

Comment: RestTemplateBuilder is not a part of Spring framework 3.2. I've specified this in the question. Can you please provide a solution for spring framework 3.2.

Comment: My mistake. Added an alternative solution.

Answer (score 0):

The `HttpClient` can be built from the [HttpClientBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html#setDefaultHeaders(java.util.Collection)).

This builder has `setDefaultHeaders(Collection<? extends org.apache.http.Header> defaultHeaders)` method which you can set the headers you want. Then when you want an `HttpClient`, call `httpClientBuilder.build()`.